# Cache-Tags in Symfony2/Twig?

Tags: caching, symfony, twig, zend-cache

I'm looking for something similar to Zend_Cache-Tags in Symfony2. The aim is caching different parts of the page and clean up the cache-parts, if the related data changes.

An Example: A shop-overview could tagged with 'article-2', 'article-5'...

How can I manage it in symfony2? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 supports ESI (Edge side include) Caching. You can Tag and cache only parts. Perhaps its what you mean.

[Symfony2 ESI Caching](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html#edge-side-includes)

Comment: What I mean is the control for the cache. So it is possible, in Zends world, to clear the cache related to certain items.

If article 5 were edited, you're able to clean all cache related only to article 5.

Comment: Hmm ok but i think its not possible. Then you need something that know that the cache has changed. You can try it with varnish. 

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/cache/varnish.html